# Gtk 3 - where and how do I specify the contents of the main loop?

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk3

I am attempting to write a simple 'game loop' with GTK 3. I have created a GL context and attempted to clear it. However, the window that displays just has some black and white rectangles, probably the 'placeholder' display. Obviously the color clearing belongs inside the main loop, or it will only be executed once, but I haven't been able to figure out how to register my own main loop. Should I override gtk_main or replace it altogether?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *win, *area;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Hello, GNU");
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(win), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), 480, 480);
    g_signal_connect(win, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    area = gtk_gl_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), area);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
    gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(area));
    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

`g_signal_connect` seems to be relevant, however the signals appear to be specific events, like activating, closing, etc.

Comment: You can use the `add_idle` or `add_timeout` functions to register your custom callback function(s). Unfortunately I don't know how that works in c++ since I'm coming from a python background, but here's a [link to the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html).

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use a toolkit more adapted to game programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the OpenGL code, but here is an example you may be able to adapt to OpenGL, showing how a callback can update a [GdkPixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html).

```
//g++ test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int width = 320, height = 240;

GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new (GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, width, height);
int rowstride = gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf);
guchar *pixels = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf);
GtkImage *image;

inline void drawPixel (int x, int y, char red, char green, char blue)
{
    *(pixels + y * rowstride + x * 3) = red;
    *(pixels + y * rowstride + x * 3 + 1) = green;
    *(pixels + y * rowstride + x * 3 + 2) = blue;
}

gboolean game_loop (GtkWidget *widget, GdkFrameClock *clock, gpointer data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            drawPixel(i, j, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
        }
    }
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (image, pixbuf);  
    return 1;
} 

int main()
{
    gtk_init (NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *window, *box;
    image = GTK_IMAGE (gtk_image_new());
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), GTK_WIDGET(image), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_add_tick_callback(window, game_loop, NULL, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

Result:

[image: gdkpixbuf]